# Set using namespaces for all files in a folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using-directives

Is there a way to set the namespaces references for all files within a folder?

Example: All my classes in a certain folder needs to reference `System.ComponentModel` (and many others) and I don't want to set the references every time I create a new class.

Comment: If this is for work, get your boss to spring for Resharper or CodeRush which makes this (and 100s of other little annoyances) pretty painless.

Comment: Just starting !  But I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Each file represents a separate *compilation unit* and the C# language specification [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces):

> A C# program consists of one or more compilation units, each contained in a separate source file.
>
> …
>
> The using_directives of a compilation unit … have no effect on other compilation units.

As others suggested, development tools that integrate with Visual Studio are typically used to perform such routine tasks as generating and maintaining the set of `using`s in each file.

Comment: Thougth it would be a basic feature. Thanks